Degeneracy in time-independent perturbation theory
I have a problem understanding the reasoning of my professor in Quantum Mechanics. The topic is time-independent perturbation theory.

Let $H = H_0 + \lambda H_1$ be a perturbed Hamilton-Operator and consider the ansatz for the eigenvalue $E_n$ and eigenstate $|n\rangle$:
$$E_n = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} E_n^{i} \lambda^i \quad , \qquad |n\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |n^{i}\rangle \lambda^i \quad ,$$
where the $E_n^i$ and $|n^i\rangle$ do not (!) denote powers of $i$ but rather series expansion coefficients. Then by multiplying the time-independent Schrödinger equation $H |n \rangle = E_n |n\rangle$ with the dual ONB $\langle m^0 |$ to $H_0$ and considering only terms that are linear in $\lambda$, the usual first order energy state correction reads:
$$( E_m^0 - E_n^0 ) \langle m^0 | n^1 \rangle + \langle m^0 | H_1 | n^0 \rangle = E_n^1 \delta_{mn} \tag{1}$$
In the degenerate case, where (say) the first $r$ eigenvalues coincide $E_0^0 = \ldots = E_r^0$, the equation reduces to
$$\langle m^0 | H_1 | n^0 \rangle = E_n^1 \delta_{mn}$$
for $n \in \{1, \ldots, r\}$. Now my professor states, that there is a problem for $m  \neq n$ because in general $\langle m^0 | H_1 | n^0 \rangle$ is non-diagonal and so we have a contradiction, which is resolved by switching to another ONB. However, I do not understand this reasoning. Isn't the converse true? That the above equation actually shows that $\langle m^0 | H_1 | n^0 \rangle$ indeed MUST BE diagonal? In order to arrive at equation (1), one did not use the fact that $H_0$ is degenerate, so why can one just "ignore" the equations derived from it?

This is a complicated topic that is very highly duplicated. Have you looked some of them up? Your prof is correct and you are wrong. In the derivation, Equation (1) is a consistency relation and must hold true. However, $\left<m^0|H_1|n^0\right>$ is made of $H_0$ eigenstates and your perturbation, both of which are fixed and cannot be set to be diagonal if you have chosen standard "bad" eigenstates. The other two terms in Equation (1) are zeroed, so then you have an inconsistent equation, and the entire perturbation scheme breaks down. Your prof is trying to get you to understand this.

I am confused, I am afraid. If as you say equation (1) is a consistency relation and must hold true, how come it becomes inconsistent? In other words: at what point in the derivation of equation (1) does it break down when considering degeneracy? I have looked at some similary questions, but have not found one that treats the same problem and has satisfying answers (or at least ones that I understand).

Because of the inherent extra complication coming from degeneracy, which every presenter understands to be a silly complication that would be solved by imposing diagonalisation, profs will teach by first assuming no degeneracy. Then Equation (1) can always be satisfied, and the perturbation scheme is consistent. However, once you have degeneracy, Equation (1) is no longer automatically satisfied, and the solution is to adopt, by way of diagonalisation, a new set of $\left|n^0\right>$ so that the offending term is zeroed. I really suggest you find a textbook, because they tend to be better.
